# What files should I source control with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker

I've been using a MongoDB instance in my docker compose script. I want to set it up so I can keep my database from PC to PC but have all the same data.

There seems to be quite a bit of files in a MongoDB docker installation, .lock, .turtle, .wt, .bson diagnostic.data, journal etc.

Is there a rule of thumb of what I should store and would I should ignore in my repo? It's been unclear to me, I don't want to store anyfiles that could effect booting on another docker container.

Comment: Do you commit the entire docker image to your repo? Normally you should commit only the docker compose yaml

Comment: just means the docker compose I believe

Answer (score 0):

Best is to preserve everything under the mongod dbPath folder , but some files/folders can be removed afcourse like diagnostic.data - the folder contain collected metrics during operation necessary for performance analysis at later stage , but in general the already collected stats are not necessary for the mongod process to be executed.

Comment: assuming you mean /data/db?

Comment: Exactly /data/db  in docker , but this can be changed from mongod.conf -> dbPath: ''